# Getting "ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package" when loading Cogs

Tags: python, discord.py, python-import

I've bee looking up questions with the same issues for a long time, but none seem to solve my issue.

I'm currently trying to load the Cogs for my bot, but whenever I do so, I  get the error: "ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package":

```
> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site -
> Projet\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 935,
> in _load_from_module_spec
>     spec.loader.exec_module(lib)  # type: ignore   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module   File
> "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site - Projet\discord-bot\Cogs\base.py", line 2, in <module>
>     from ..main import client ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package The above exception was the direct cause of
> the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site - Projet\discord-bot\main.py",
> line 44, in <module>
>     asyncio.run(main())   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py",
> line 44, in run
>     return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 647, in run_until_complete
>     return future.result()   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site - Projet\discord-bot\main.py", line 36, in main
>     await load()   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site - Projet\discord-bot\main.py", line 29, in load
>     await client.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site -
> Projet\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1013,
> in load_extension
>     await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Site -
> Projet\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 938,
> in _load_from_module_spec
>     raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'Cogs.base'
> raised an error: ImportError: attempted relative import beyond
> top-level package*
```

My file structure is the following:

```
├── Project6 (directory)
     ├── discord-bot (directory)
     |  ├── main.py (file)
     |  ├── Cogs (directory)
     |     └── base.py (file)
     └── Unrelated files
```

Here is the code to load the cogs in main.py:

```
async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('Cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        else:
            print("Couldn't log the Cogs.")

Start = 'TOKEN'

async def main():
    await load()
    await client.start(Start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And here is the one in base.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
from ..main import client


class BASE(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @client.command()
        async def training(ctx):
            print('a')



def setup(bot):
    client.add_cog(BASE(bot))
```

I've tried changing "from ..main import client" to "from main import client", "from main import *", and "import main", but none of these works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using discord.py version >= 2.0

You should not import your main script into a cog file. Consider using `commands.command` inside an extension with your cog.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class BASE(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def training(self, ctx):
        print('a')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(BASE(bot))
```

Looking at the code you provided, you don't seem to be familiar with OOP in Python, please also consider learning about OOP before proceeding with any project that incorporates the ideas of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

In the base.py file try this:

```
async def setup(bot):
    await client.add_cog(BASE(bot))
```

and also change `client.command` to `commands.command`

Comment: I've done that, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also delete this line: `from ..main import client`

Comment: Client is still used in "await client.add_cog(BASE(bot))".

Comment: try and change that to bot.add_cog